# Upgrading CentOS web server

Tags: centos, upgrade, webserver

Have just taken over control of a CentOS 6.4 web server with Apache.

My question is, to update the server software, is it a case of just using `yum update` and then `yum upgrade`?

Server has been neglected until now so need to install new security patches etc, but I don't (obviously) want to risk losing clients' documents / sites.

Comment: FYI, 6.4 isn't what I would call a neglected server 8-).

Comment: @slm It's more the security side than the actual version itself

Comment: Is there (a) MySQL or PostGres database installed? If MySQL shows up as installed and being updated, there is some pre-update and post-update work you should do as well. I don't know the steps for PostGres though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes just running `yum update` and `yum upgrade` is how you would approach this. You'll need to pay special attention if there are any applications that require PHP, Perl, etc. that are called through a module within Apache.

You can also do a `yum check-update` to get a sense of how much will be touched prior to running the actual update.

Comment: Is the update likely to affect PHP and PERL? I thought I would have to update them separately? I only really want to install the security update. The server has been hacked and need to do what I can to prevent it happening again

Comment: You can list what's going to be updated and selectively upgrade packages. See `man yum`.

Comment: @matt1985 - it might if you don't specify what to update: `yum update apache`, for example.